# Is there a way to get Postfix to both forward an e-mail *and* reject it via recipient_address_rejected

Tags: postfix, email-bounces

In postfix, I'd like a way to deal with e-mail accounts that are no longer active by having postfix send the standard "Recipient address rejected" type message, but still forwarding the e-mail to another user.  Thus, if someone sends an e-mail to employee.who.quit@example.com, it will bounce the message back to the sender for future reference, but the mail will still get forwarded to active.employee@example.com to deal with.   .vacation and / or .forward files let me down because they will either reply or forward, but not both.  Any tips?

Comment: What we do is use the `.forward` file to forward to the new employee + send an auto-reply giving the new contact. After a few months, we remove the old account and it's forwarding, and replace it with an entry in the `relocated_maps`, which rejects the mail with the new contact details in the error message text

Answer (score 2):

You are violating RFC 5321. Don't to that! Rejecting mails is definitively okay in this case. Go for that.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than issuing a bounce and forwarding, you should issue an auto-reply and forward.

As observed in the answer by @mailq , what you're proposing violates an RFC, so you shouldn't do it, and probably won't find find many options for doing so.  Instead, redirect it, and handle the auto-reply however you prefer (from the new address or the old one).

Answer (score -2):

After looking at [`header_checks(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) and [`pcre_checks(5)`](http://www.postfix.org/pcre_table.5.html), I would experiment with putting something like this in the `header_checks` file:

```
if /^To: employee.who.quit*/
REDIRECT active.employee@example.com
REJECT "This individual no longer works at example.com."
endif
```

Now, the man paged I linked to says I can't use `REJECT` in `header_check`, but I haven't had a chance to look into why that might be true, and it may not be. (I can think of arguments both ways.) If `REJECT` doesn't work, I'd next experiment with `FILTER` to send the email to an MDA that would handle the reply to the sender.

Alternately, I might also look at `.forward` sending to an automated mail handler that does its own redirects and replies to sender.

Comment: Rejected mails can't be forwarded. Forwarded mails can't be rejected. So both provided solutions don't work.